# How to save append return in Lisp variable?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun test(n x)
   (let* (d (append (list n) x)))
   (if (= n 0) d
      (test (- n 1) d)))
```

So this is a basic test function I'm writing in lisp. The function is supposed to take a number(n) and a list(x) in and appends every number between n and 0 to a list which is returned. However, when I run it, e.g.

```
(test 4 NIL)
```

it says

> bad binding form: (APPEND (LIST N) X)

Basically my question is how do you store the return call from append into a variable in Lisp?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parentheses around the bindings and your code is not in the body of the `let*` but outside making `d` a special global variable. You should have got a warning about that. Since you are using only one binding the use of `let*` instead of `let` is unnecessary.

```
(defun test (n x)
  (let ((d (append (list n) x)))
    (if (= n 0)
        d
        (test (- n 1) d))))
```

Note that since you are adding elements to the beginning of the list ou should use `cons` instead of `append` + `list` like this:

```
(defun test (n x)
  (let ((d (cons n x)))
    (if (= n 0)
        d
        (test (- n 1) d))))
```

I also notice that if your base case goes one step further you don't need the binding:

```
(defun make-range (to &optional (acc '()))
  "Makes a list of the elements from 0 to to"
  (if (< to 0)
      acc
      (make-range (- to 1) (cons to acc)))))

(make-range 5)
; ==> (0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: Rename the function also in the recursive call.